# c++ thread alive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

How to?

I tried a WaitingForSingleObject, GetExitCodeThread and etc., but when i kill thread with process explorer nothing happens.

```
while(true)
{
    if(GetThreadId(this->hWatchThread) == 0) // Always return killed thread id!
        break;
}
```

**Upd:**
When i kill thread, it stop working, but i can't get exit code or zero value from `GetThreadId`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if a Win32 thread has terminated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301054/how-can-i-determine-if-a-win32-thread-has-terminated)

Comment: No, WaitForSingleObject never return value.

Comment: Yes it does, reliably. I'm using that in many projects.

Comment: Yes it return value when thread exit when finish work, but not when i kill it manually.

Comment: How are you creating the thread in the first place? WaitForSingleObject on the thread handle would be a standard solution here, but there are traps - for example you have to make sure the thread doesn't automatically release its own handle.

Comment: You probably kill the **process**, not the thread. Obviously, killing the process does not output anything further. Killing the thread manually (from your own program or from Process Explorer) certainly makes `WaitForSingleObject` return. Regarding your update, note that _there is no exit code_ when you kill a thread. As an analogy, imagine asking someone for his name after cutting his throat. How do you expect to get an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread is killed forcibly, e.g. from the task manager or from Process Explorer, that does not change the thread ID. The thread handle still exists because your process has not yet closed it. And the thread ID associated with that thread still exists. So `GetThreadId` will always return a non-zero value.

As for the exit code, you can't get a meaningful value for the exit code because the thread did not exit. It was killed. It never had a chance to set an exit code.

What you must do is use one of the wait functions, e.g. `WaitForSingleObject`, to wait on your thread handle. If that wait terminates because the thread was killed, then the wait function will return and report a successful wait and the thread exit code will be reported as `0`. To the best of my knowledge you cannot discern by means of the Windows API that your thread was killed abnormally.

What you could do is use your own mechanism to indicate that termination was abnormal. Create a flag, owned by the thread, to record that termination was normal. Set the flag to false when the thread starts executing. When the thread terminates normally, set the flag to true. This way you can tell whether or not the thread was terminated abnormally by reading the value of that flag after the thread terminates.

Comment: An example of a boolean flag? Surely you can work that out. Set it to false at the start of your thread proc, or even better, before you even create the thread. Then set it to true just before your thread proc exits.

Comment: And how i get status of thread? If it always false, i can't know when it die.

Comment: You have to call `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for it to terminate. Or call `GetExitCodeThread` to check asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something after the thread has exited:

```
WaitForSingleObject(handle_to_your_thread,INFINITE);
MessageBox(NULL,"Thread has exited","Foo",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```